# Zoom in and zoom out images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I zoom in and zoom out images, like Google Maps, using mouse scroll in Javascript? Is there any jQuery framework that supports this feature?

Comment: What have you trued? Where are you stuck? This isn't the script shopping channel.

Comment: Found a jquery Plugin : http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos

Comment: Here you will find some examples: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=examples